# dexlib2 - Branch coverage instrumentation

Tags: smali

I am trying to instrument smali code using dexlib2 in order to measure branch
coverage. In particular, I am inserting at each branch (if and corresponding label) basically two instructions; const-string to load a unique trace for each branch and invoke-static to call a static method. However, there are a couple of issues:

First, I had to increase the number of register by one. This led to re-arranging
the registers of certain instructions, which seems to work (used reflection to increase the register number, e.g. originally p0 got v20 by introducing a new local register v21). However, I have noticed that certain labels, e.g. .end local v15 also would require this sort
of modification, which seems to be not possible with dexlib2, since the labels
don't track this kind of information nor a name. I am also unaware what's the meaning/intention of those .end/.restart./start local labels. Are those labels
interesting for garbage collection or also some kind of type information for
the corresponding registers?

Second, certain instructions only accept as arguments v0-v15. That's why
I had to differentiate whether the number of local registers exceeds 16 or not.
In this case, I basically use two additional move instructions:
(in the other case, the instrumentation is much easier)

move-object/16 vNew, v0 # save value of v0
(two above mentioned instructions) # use v0 for keeping the trace
move-object/16 v0, vNew # restore value of v0

However, recently I am getting the following error (and similar verify errors):

[0x25C] 'this' argument 'Reference: java.lang.Object' not instance of 'Reference: com.android.calendar.GeneralPreferences'

I have observed that it makes a difference between using move and move-object, but I am unaware of the concrete difference. I would assume that constants
are non-objets while the rest represents objects. If this distinction is necessary, I would have to perform some analysis of v0's last type at each branch, which makes everything even more complicated.

Third, I have noticed that the labels associated with branches are somewhat
behaving strange in some rare cases. There are branches in the entire smali
file that gets instrumented twice. Debugging reveals that querying the
if instruction for its target labels (the other branch) one time returns
more labels than the other time. That's why I now use the index of the
target label (instruction.getTarget().getLocation().getIndex()), but I still obtain a single branch, which gets instrumented twice.

I am asking for any help on that particular matter as well as general hints/facts
I should consider. Is there a better way to get more detailed information about
errors; the output of logcat is not the best, e.g. which particular instruction
caused the verify error (the hexadecimal value treated as offest doesn't make
any sense for me).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "querying the if instruction for its target labels (the other branch) one time returns more labels than the other time." - can you provide a code sample or something? I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: I basically maintained the labels corresponding to an if branch in a set of set of labels and only instrumented those branches, where the set of labels isn't included

Comment: Yeah, there's still not enough detail for me to have any clue about that last part :)

Comment: Sorry, unintended end of comment. :(I basically maintained the labels corresponding to an if branch in a set of set of labels (Set<Set<Label>>) and only instrumented those branches, where the set of labels isn't included in the set. However, by looping through the instructions of a specific method and requesting the corresponding labels for if-instructions, I noticed that the returned set of labels differs in the amount of labels (one time more/less) for two if-instructions that share a common target label (the same branch).

Comment: The Label class doesn't currently override hashCode or provide any value equality semantics, so you're probably adding duplicate labels to the set. i.e. 2 different instances for the same label/location. Feel free to send a pull request to add value equality semantics to that class :)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I provided a wrapper class around those labels, which primarily checks the index of the MethodLocation and additionally the codeAddress if the index is the same for two labels, i.e.                               return this.index == o.index || this.codeAddress == o.codeAddress;                    I guess the second check is causing the problem, since the index is the same but through the instrumentation the codeAddress potentially changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've seen to deal with the issues you noticed when increasing register count is to add a prologue that moves all post-increase parameter register back to their pre-increase locations, and then use the last register/registers as the new "scratch" registers.

e.g. if the parameters were at v14-v20, and you increase the register count by one, you would add code that would move v15 back to v14, v16 back to v15, etc. and use v21 as the new scratch register.

Alternately, you can try not to allocate any registers. e.g. create a new method, and pass in the value from the target method that you want to instrument. You can use invoke-*/range to pass in any single register. But in your case, this doesn't seem too feasible, since you want to pass in an additional string to identify the branch. You could theoretically create a new method for every branch, but you'll run into method limits in no time that way.

---

.end/.restart./start local are purely for debugging information. They tell the debugger which register is associated with which local variable in the original java code. The easiest thing would be to just strip them. See https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format#debug-info-item for more information.

---

Yes, move-object must be used for reference types, move-wide for primitive longs/doubles, and move for other primitives. Also, don't forget that wide types take up 2 registers. So if you may need to allocate 2 extra scratch registers if you happen to need to move a wide value (a long or double primitive)

dexlib2 has an api for performing type analysis on registers, if needed. See https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/blob/master/dexlib2/src/main/java/org/jf/dexlib2/analysis/MethodAnalyzer.java

Comment: My idea is to derive the type of v0 (the one I need for the actual instrumentation) and insert below each instruction modifying v0 an additional instruction const vNew (the scratch register) type, where type is either 0,1 or 2 denoting non-object, object or wide. Then, I simply wrap my instrumentation code with an if, which uses move-wide, move or move-object depending on the type. I guess this avoids the complexity of determining the type v0 at every branch statically. Can you suggest a cheap way of determining instructions that modify v0 in a given method?

Comment: It's not quite that simple, unfortunately. Consider, for example, if there are 2 branches that both jump to the same target location, but the type of v0 is different in each branch. Once you're at the branch target, if the types aren't compatible, then the type of the register is indeterminate (which also means you can safely clobber its contents).

Comment: Ok, I see. @JesusFreke, the method analyzer you suggested throws UnresolvedClassExceptions for standard classes like Exception/StringBuilder and even some primitive type like Boolean or Double. Do you have any idea what's the cause of this problem?

Comment: Normally, the analyzer is used with a full classpath from a device. But it should still work even without that, although it won't be able to provide full type information - but determining whether a register is normal/wide/reference should be fine. A stack trace would be useful to try and figure out what's going on. And that sounds like a separate question :)